# Does Copy TBytes create a TRUE copy?

Tags: arrays, delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

```
function TFormMain.GetMyTBytes(const AFileName: string): TBytes;
begin
  with TFileStream.Create(AFileName, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyNone) do
  try
    SetLength(Result, Size);
    ReadBuffer(PByte(Result)^, Size);
  finally
    Free;
  end;
end;  

// ... 

var
  TBA, TBB: TBytes;

// ...

TBA := GetMyTBytes('C:\mydoc.docx');
TBB := Copy(TBA);
```

Can it be excluded in this case that `TBB` shares any memory with `TBA` at the end of this operation?

Comment: You could test this yourself with two lines of code: `TBB[0] := TBA[0] + 1; ShowMessage(BoolToStr(TBB[0] = TBA[0], True));` in less time than it took you to open your browser, come here, and click the *Ask Question* button.

Comment: @user1580348: You could have checked the docs too, e.g. [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.Copy): "The substring or subarray is a unique copy". If you checked in code, like Ken said, or if you had read the docs, you should have mentioned that, e.g. "The documentation says ..., but can I rely on this to be true in all circumstances?" or "it says *subarray*, is this true for full arrays too?" or something like that, etc.

Comment: There are many *special cases* where code may not follow exactly what is said in the documentation. A large part of the discussion on SO (my question included) is about those possible special cases.

Comment: @user1580348: Then you should have asked *that*, i.e. "The docs say X, but can I rely on that in all cases?" or "I tried Y and they were indeed different, but is this generally true?", or something like it. The way you stated it did not indicate you tried or looked up anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Copy()` creates a duplicate of the array data in memory. There is nothing shared between `TBA` and `TBB` once the copy is made.

Also, your `GetMyTBytes()` is redundant, the `System.IOUtils` unit has a [`TFile.ReadAllBytes()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.IOUtils.TFile.ReadAllBytes) method available.